# Need to write a certain method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, equals

So I have a homework question. This is what I need to do:

> Write the definition of a method ,  oddsMatchEvens , whose two parameters  are arrays  of integers  of equal  size. The size of each array  is an even number. The method  returns true  if and only if the even-indexed elements  of the first array  equal  the odd-indexed elements  of the second, in sequence. That is if w is the first array  and q the second array , w[0] equals  q[1], and w[2] equals  q[3], and so on.

What I have is:

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens(int[] w, int[] q){
int count = 0;

for(int i=0; i < w.length; i++){
if(w[i].equals(q[i + 1])){
count++;
if(count == w.length){
return true;
}
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
⇒     You almost certainly should be using: &&
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: +=
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: >=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(w[i] == q[i + 1])
```

The 'equals' methos is used for objects.

And of course a boolean must ALWAYS be returned.

A working version of the method:

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens(int[] w, int[] q) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        if (w[i] == q[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            if (count == w.length) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The list goes on I'm afraid, but should get him started, hes almost there I'm sure.

Comment: @DaViDa, what is the error you get now? I'm thinking you're missing a return statement (you return `true` if it's correct, but you never return `false`).

Comment: Indeed I'll edit my answer to show the entire working method maybe that will help.

Comment: More Hints:
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: &&
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: +=
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: >=

Problems Detected:
     ⇒     Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 occurred
     ⇒     oddsMatchEvens() does not return the correct value

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens(int[] w, int[] q){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; w.length >= i; i++){
        count += 1;
        if(w[i] == q[i + 1] && count == w.length){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this code i am getting the error:     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: <
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: a
     ⇒     You almost certainly should be using: b

Comment: @DaViDa: Now I do not know what that is meaning. it was '<' before now we changed und it isn't good as well?? At what means a and b?

Comment: Yea the home work site is called myprogramminglab, I am getting that error when I put in your code. Sometimes they want the answer to be written differently.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the return outside the for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i < w.length; i++){.....}   
return count==w.length;
```